# How to zip specific named folders?

Tags: zip

I have the directory structure shown below. I would like to create a zip file containing only `point_clouds`. I tried using the wildcard but it doesn't work.

`blender:~/data$ zip -r test.zip *point_clouds`

How can I zip only the `point_clouds` subfolders but keep the structure the same? I don't need the other non zipped subfolders.

```
data/
    Kallax_Shelf_Drawer/
        sequence1/
        sequence2/
        sequence3/
           dev3/
           frames/
           point_clouds/
    Lack_Coffee_Table/
        sequence1/
        sequence2/
        sequence3/
           dev3/
           frames/
           point_clouds/
    Lack_TV_Bench/
        sequence1/
        sequence2/
        sequence3/
           dev3/
           frames/
           point_clouds/
    Lack_Side_Table/
        sequence1/
        sequence2/
        sequence3/
           dev3/
           frames/
           point_clouds/
```

Comment: Does `zip -r test.zip Data/*/sequence?/point_clouds` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
zip -r data/*/*/point_clouds
```

will do. These wildcards expand to valid relative paths to your "point_clouds" folders. The command will create a "point_clouds.zip" file in the current folder containing only the contents of each of the "point_clouds" folders with the directory structure preserved.